# Pass data to transcluded repeated element from repeating component

Tags: angularjs, angular, transclusion

In Angular 2 I want to put something line `ng-content` into `ngFor` inside of my component. But the problem is I need to pass some data ito the transcluded element.

I [found](//stackoverflow.com/a/32319422/4928642) following solution for AgularJS:
http://plnkr.co/edit/aZKFqPJmPlfTVRffB0Cc?p=preview

```
.directive("foo", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {},
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){

      scope.items = [1, 2, 3, 4];

      var template = '<h1>I am foo</h1>\
                      <div ng-repeat="$item in items">\
                        <placeholder></placeholder>\
                      </div>';
      var templateEl = angular.element(template);

      transclude(scope, function(clonedContent){
        templateEl.find("placeholder").replaceWith(clonedContent);

        $compile(templateEl)(scope, function(clonedTemplate){
          element.append(clonedTemplate);
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

How can I make the same thing in Angular 2?

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/551347/178988)

Comment: could you please elaborate bit more ? what you want in angular2 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ngForTemplate` like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `
        <h1>I am foo</h1>
        <div>
         <template ngFor [ngForOf]="data" [ngForTemplate]="itemTemplate"></template>
        </div>`
})
export class Foo {
    @Input() data: any[];
    @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
    <foo [data]="items">
        <template let-item>
            <div>item: {{item}}</div>
        </template>
    </foo>
 `,
  directives: [Foo],

})
export class AppComponent {
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/mpuQse2QuyP7QHXL7wM1?p=preview)**

Or instead `template let-item` you can write:

```
<foo [data]="items">
   <div template="let item">item: {{item}}</div>
</foo>
```

**[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/jB4qzx9Zd3JLkyenu9f3?p=preview)**

Comment: Great! [Checked](//plnkr.co/edit/VzT9koNXzAx3B1qvHuJ8?p=preview) some more details - it works even better than I wanted!

Comment: What if I need additional wrapping element for repeating item?