# List item renderer in Angular 2

Tags: templates, angular

I got "dumb" list component that uses another "dumb" component to render single item. And when I want to pass data to renderers I got to have same property in my list component. For example if I want to have "showTimestamp" boolean property for item I got to do this:

list.template.html

```
<my-item-renderer *ngFor="let item of items" [showTimestamp]="showTimestamp"></my-item-renderer>
```

Is there a way to do something to replace part of component template?

I would like to do something like this:

```
<my-list [items]="items"><ng-content><item-renderer [showTimestamp]="true"></item-renderer></ng-content></my-list>
```

So my list get just items property and in ng-content gets a renderer with already set showTimestamp variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template for this:

```
<my-list [items]="items">
  <template><item-renderer [showTimestamp]="true"></item-renderer></template></my-list>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  template: `
      <template ngFor [ngForOf]="items" [ngForTemplate]="templateRef"></template>`
})
class MyList {
  @Input() data;
  constructor(private templateRef:TemplateRef) {}
}
```

See also

- [Binding events when using a ngForTemplate in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730210/binding-events-when-using-a-ngfortemplate-in-angular-2)
- [Pass data to transcluded repeated element from repeating component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38466490/pass-data-to-transcluded-repeated-element-from-repeating-component/38466789#38466789)
- [Angular2 child component as data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755844/angular2-child-component-as-data/36760027#36760027)

Comment: I get "No provider for TemplateRef" error in runtime when using your code.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd link use `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;` instead of constructor injection. Can you please try that instead. It's a while I used this myself.

Comment: Thanks! `@ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef;` is working.